# how can I sum the last x value per each group

Tags: python, pandas

Let say i have the table below.
{

```
|Country        | Year | investment |
|Afghanistan    |2020  |    NaN     |
|Afghanistan    |2019  |    45      |
|Afghanistan    |2018  |    NaN     |
|Afghanistan    |2017  |    NaN     |
|Afghanistan    |2016  |    24      |
|Afghanistan    |2015  |    27      |
|Afghanistan    |2014  |    30      |
|Afghanistan    |2013  |    15      |
|Afghanistan    |2014  |    11.12   |
|.              |.     |.           |
|.              |.     |.           |
|.              |.     |.           |
|Zimbabwe       |2020  |    30.12   |   
|Zimbabwe       |2019  |    20.5    |
|Zimbabwe       |2018  |    18.2    |
|Zimbabwe       |2017  |    25.2    |
```

I want to create a new column per that reads total investment in the previous 3 years.
only if there is 3 years worth of data (no NaN)

the new table would have the values below (this only for Afghanistan)

```
|10 year investment|
|NaN               |
|NaN               |
|NaN               |
|81                |
|72                |
|56.12             |
```

I have tried the code below but cannot get it to work.
It works when i remove the groupby

`df['10 year investment'] = df.groupby('Country').sort_values(by='Year', ascending =False)['investment'].rolling(min_periods=3, window=3).sum()`

the following works but its not grouped

`df['10 year investment'] = df.sort_values(by='Year', ascending =False)['investment'].rolling(min_periods=3, window=3).sum()`

Comment: You can use the `{}` button in the editor around the table to create a code block. HTML/Markdown tables aren't really cleanly written

Answer (score 0):

adding reset index fixed it.

`df['10 year investment'] = df.sort_values(by='Year', ascending =False).groupby('Country')['investment'].rolling(min_periods=3, window=3).sum().reset_index(0,drop=True)`